# Google Geocoding API HTTP Request denied - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, geocoding

The following (and other similar) HTTP request to the Google geocoding API comes out correctly when I paste it into my browser

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false
```

And when I do the following in Ruby

```
url = URI.parse('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false')
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}
puts res.body
```

I get

```
{
"results" : [],
"status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

This is the same error I get when not setting the "sensor" property for example, but that's not the problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `#request_uri` instead of `#path`, or your query parameters will not be included:

```
url = URI.parse('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false')

url.path
# => "/maps/api/geocode/json"

url.request_uri
# => "/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false"
```

Comment: You're a gentleman and a scholar! The SO question from which I got the HTTP request code even had a comment with that as a caveat, and guess who ignored it? This guy! Thanks Lars.